# Ajax JSON exception Unexpected token [

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

hi i have a page contains a link , when user click the link i want to go to database and retrieve two arrays , but when i alert those two arrays i got this exception

```
Unexpected token [
```

this is my js code

```
function acNewConcpet(element){
    var parent = element.parentNode;
    parent.removeChild(element);
    var concpetSelect = document.createElement('select');
    var relationSelect = document.createElement('select');
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 &&  xmlhttp.status==200){
            var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            alert(data);
        }

    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost/Mar7ba/Ontology/getRelatedConceptsAndRelations/"+"concept"+"/TRUE",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

and this is my php code

```
public function getRelatedConceptsAndRelations($concpetName, $Ajax) {
        if ($Ajax) {
            $concepts = array('c1', 'c2');
            $relations = array('r1','r2');
            echo json_encode($concepts);
            echo json_encode($relations);
        }
        return;
}
```

why is this exception ? and how can i solve it ? and how can i receive those two arrays in my js ?
this is full code [code](http://jsfiddle.net/H5Un4/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you response a JSON, it needs to be one JSON, but you are sending two seperate arrays.

Merge those two JSONs into one.

**Update:**

Do it like this:

```
public function getRelatedConceptsAndRelations($concpetName, $Ajax) {
    if ($Ajax) {
        $concepts = array('c1', 'c2');
        $relations = array('r1','r2');
        echo json_encode(array($concepts, $relations));
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Your terminology is not quite right. [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object."](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: Yes I know, somewhy I'm still using this terminology... my bad.

Answer (score 3):

`JSON.parse` can only parse a **single** JSON literal.

You should combine the two arrays into a single object with two properties.

Comment: u mean somthing like this $newArrya = array($concepts,$relations?) , if u mean that , so i did that and still see that exception

Answer (score 3):

You are returning malformed JSON. From what I understand from your code, it prints out this JSON:

```
['c1','c2']['r1,r2']
```

You cant have 2 arrays like this. You must print it like:

```
[['c1','c2'],['r1','r2']]
```

Sorry for my rusty PHP, but you must have something like:

```
$json = array(
    array('c1','c2'),
    array('r1','r2')
);

echo json_encode($json);
```

---

Since you are using jQuery, why not use [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)?

```
$.getJSON(url,function(returnData){
    //returnData is the parsed JSON
});
```

Comment: still the same error , but u helped me in ur array , really u right , i should make them as one array , thank you man

Comment: i never tried jQuery with JSON , i will try ur suggestion now

Comment: is it like this ?document.ready(function (){
    $('.smallLink').click(function(){
        $.getJSON(url,function (retur)){
            
        }
        });
});